# Finitely generated skew-fields

Tags: ra.rings-and-algebras, noncommutative-algebra, noncommutative-rings

There is a well known theorem saying that a commutative field that is finitely generated as a ring has to be finite (Kaplansky).

Is the same true for non-commutative "fields" (usually called skewfields or division rings)?

I have searched for this problem on the internet, but the only reference I have found was a notice on a related question in the book of P.M.Cohn: Skew Fields - Theory of General Division Rings (1995)  p. 412 [here](https://books.google.cz/books?id=u-4ADgUgpSMC&pg=PA412&lpg=PA412&dq=finitely+generated+skew+fields+are+finite&source=bl&ots=TNjPalQHkI&sig=jYQ6x6Kh1-_9jv3uoUKRaUpB4GQ&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwj6sNjBvLPVAhUFKsAKHXZkB7w4ChDoAQgsMAI#v=onepage&q=finitely%20generated%20skew%20fields%20are%20finite&f=false):

Let $L$ be a skewfield finitely generated as a ring over a subfield $K$. Is $L$ necessarily algebraic over $K$?

At that time this question was open as well. Does anybody know some recent references on any of these problems? Thank you in advance.

Comment: In these slides from a 2014 talk of Agata Smoktunowicz your first question is called the "Latyshev problem" and listed as an unsolved problem: http://www.maths.lth.se/nordic26/media/uploads/smoktunowicz.pdf